# Would you rather vs Would you rather see

Tags: word-choice, grammar, sentence

I saw the following sentence on a website:

Would you rather Ronaldo or Messi in your team.

This sounds weird to me, I would say: *Would you rather have/see Ronaldo or Messi in your team*

Is it okay to just use ''rather'' without anything behind it, because it sounds quite unnatural to my ears.

Comment: It sounds a bit odd to me, too, but as an American I would not be entirely surprised to hear a British person omit "have" or "see."  Can you link to the example?

Comment: I also think ***on*** *your team* is much more appropriate than ***in***

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a common construction in the US, but it's not unknown and would be easily understood (and not a red flag for "illiterate") when used in a reasonable context.  Has a British sense to it -- best said with the pinkie finger elevated.

Comment: I'm not much of a soccer player but I can hear both versions as correct.  The more authentic for me is *in*.  When these things mattered to me I was always hoping to be *in* the best team.

Comment: @phoog It was on Mirror Football's facebook page, I believe it's from the UK. Anyways, thanks for the replies. It's clear to me now

Answer (score 5):

This is *quite* a common, informal usage (UK) where the (obvious) verb is simply not spoken.

(Question from a busy canteen server) *Would you rather coffee or tea ?*

Clearly the context must be clear and the missing verb obvious.

Comment: I'm British and I've never heard this usage.